# Partial sums for $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^j}$ and similar.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to take the limit of a series involving $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^j}$ and thinking
that this might have a partial sum representation.

Here it says that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^{i-1}} = \frac{3}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3^n})$ is the partial sum representation for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^{i-1}}$: 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ConvergenceOfSeries.aspx

But how is this derived?

Comment: There is no "partial fraction" here.

Comment: @Did Ah correct. It's "partial sum".

Comment: By the by, did you try the obvious before asking this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: @Did No, because I was mistakenly looking for "partial fractions", since the series I'm dealing with has actually multiplicative terms, where $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^j}$ is one such term.

Comment: Or of [Partial sum of a geometric series](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/636308)

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with the formula for the [sum of the first n terms of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$ or something similar?

Using this formula you easily get: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3^{i-1}} =\sum\limits_{i=1-1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3^{(i+1)-1}} =\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3^i} =\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{i}$$

Can you take it from here?